# Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution.

pls help me out with the solution..

when i try to execute the sp, im getting the error

Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
Msg 8630, Level 17, State 52, Procedure USPReportPerformanceIndex_test, Line 456
Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution..

How to fix this problem..

Comment: What specific query is causing the "Internal Query Processor Error"? Do you have all updates installed?

Comment: Check this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10952/meaning-of-set-in-error-message-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-o

Comment: There is almost no information in this question to help you. Post the code that has been running and the SQL Server log output. Run DBCC CHECKDB.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you. My team experienced a similar error on the Microsoft Dynamics CRM database. A CRM  solution somehow had a dangling foreign key reference and we were getting the "Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution" error when we tried to delete this row from the table. So, here's what we did after which we were able to run the query. Please note these steps are specific to the CRM error. You can choose the steps that are applicable to you.

#### Step 1

> > Backup CRM Organisation database

#### Step 2

> > Find the dependency that has an invalid Null reference:

```
select top 10 * from DependencyBase
where RequiredComponentNodeId not in
(select DependencyNodeId from DependencyNodeBase)
```

#### Step 3

> > Put CRM Organization database in SINGLE USER MODE

#### Step 4

> > Run the following script

```
dbcc checkdb('Cap_MSCRM',repair_rebuild)
go

update statistics DependencyBase
update statistics DependencyNodeBase

delete from DependencyBase
where DependencyId = '31BB8193-DD65-40E8-9A24-E7B7E2ADACD2' –DependencyId returned in Step 2
```

#### Step 5

> > Put CRM Organization database in MULTI USER MODE

#### Step 6

> > Do IISreset